# Python rpyc can not run a psutil command remotely

Tags: python, rpyc

I'm trying to run a `psutil` command remotely:

```
import os, sys, time
import rpyc
import psutil

command = """def rpcexecute():
       import psutil
       cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
       return cpu"""

conn = rpyc.classic.connect('192.168.0.100')
conn.execute(command)
remote_exec = conn.namespace['rpcexecute']
result = remote_exec()
```

I've got an error: `"ImportError: No module named psutil"`, but I have installed `psutil` in the both (remote and localhost).

When I test using `import os` for example, it works fine.

Some tip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

I've restarted the rpyc classic service on the server and try again.
Now it works fine.

BR,

Junix

Comment: For this you will have to install rpyc and psutil in all remote servers right ?.

Comment: Yes, you have to do it.